# Localhost does not reflect controller changes for website

Tags: php, caching, xampp

I am trying to make changes to my website. It has MVC framework and uses PHP as the backend. I'm using XAMPP. No matter how many changes I do to the controller it doesn't reflect at all. I even tried to remove the contents inside my controller it still doesn't reflect the chnages. I am using a Windows PC .
Please Help

Comment: what framework are you using?

Comment: Sometimes there is OP caching. I doubt that's it but you might want to look at it. Also, of course make sure you're in the right project and in the right branch. I've had it before where I make all these changes and it is affecting a live site and not my local test site

Comment: Hello Sharol, can you please share few screenshots and code snippets for us to get a better understanding of your issue. Your question is really too broad for anyone to help you!

Answer (score -1):

There is only one reason I think changes aren't made and its the browser's cache as it is probably full.

-Simply clear it. Hope this helps